# Full Text Search with blank spaces in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

There is a problem occurs when I search data using full-text search with SQL Server 2008.

When I search data with no blank space it works but when I enter data with blank spaces it gives an error.

Like if I search `'amit'` it works but if data is `'amit is working'` it gives error.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 with SQL Server 2008.

Thanks Amit.

```
Create PROC [usp_Feedback_Search]
@Word nvarchar(500) ,   
@CompanyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     

As
IF ISNULL(@Word,'') = ''
 BEGIN
 Select          
  [Id] ,
[Content] ,    
[UserId],    
 [VoteCount] ,
 [IsOpen],
 [Deleted],
 [RowVersion],    
 [CreatedBy],     
 [CreatedOn],    
 [UpdatedOn],    
 [UpdatedBy],       
 [CompanyId], 
 [DisplayId],
  [Status]
 FROM Feedback         
  WHERE CompanyId=@CompanyId
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN   

DECLARE @formatedWord varchar(500)='"'+@word+'\+"'

  Select          
  [Id] ,
[Content] ,    
[UserId],    
 [VoteCount],
 [IsOpen],
 [Deleted],
 [RowVersion],    
 [CreatedBy],     
 [CreatedOn],    
 [UpdatedOn],    
 [UpdatedBy],       
 [CompanyId], 
 [DisplayId],
  [Status]    
  FROM Feedback            
  Where CONTAINS(*,@Word)     
  and CompanyId=@CompanyId
  END
 GO
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where it goes wrong please?

Comment: **WHAT** error does it give you`!?!? We can't see your screen or error logs from here.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dear amit you need to ignore wild card characters like @,spaces etc.

use updated code below:

```
Create PROC [usp_Feedback_Search]
@Word nvarchar(500) ,   
@CompanyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     

As
IF ISNULL(@Word,'') = ''
 BEGIN
 Select          
  [Id] ,
[Content] ,    
[UserId],    
 [VoteCount] ,
 [IsOpen],
 [Deleted],
 [RowVersion],    
 [CreatedBy],     
 [CreatedOn],    
 [UpdatedOn],    
 [UpdatedBy],       
 [CompanyId], 
 [DisplayId],
  [Status]
 FROM Feedback         
  WHERE CompanyId=@CompanyId
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN   

DECLARE @formatedWord varchar(500)='"'+@word+'\+"'

  Select          
  [Id] ,
[Content] ,    
[UserId],    
 [VoteCount] ,
 [IsOpen],
 [Deleted],
 [RowVersion],    
 [CreatedBy],     
 [CreatedOn],    
 [UpdatedOn],    
 [UpdatedBy],       
 [CompanyId], 
 [DisplayId],
  [Status]    
  FROM Feedback            
  Where CONTAINS(*,@formatedWord)     
  and CompanyId=@CompanyId
  END
 GO
```

hope this will work...
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-full-text-search-for-symbols-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 23):

I think Amit's answer may be unique to Amit. For everyone else...

**wrap the value in double quotes:**

```
SELECT ... WHERE Contains(tablename.columnname, '"amit is working"')
```

is the answer to

> *There is a problem occurs when I search data using full-text search with SQL Server 2008.*
>
> *When I search data with no blank space it works
> but when I enter data with blank spaces it gives an error.*
>
> *Like if I search 'amit' it works but if data is 'amit is working' it gives
> error.*